# Encountering errors when trying to write either a Circe encoder or decoder for ADT

Tags: scala, circe

I'm trying to write some code based on [Circe's documentation](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html), however, trying to compile both my encoder and decoder results in an error.

If you would like to take a look at the entire project, you can do so on github ([link to the file I have issues with](https://github.com/TomPoczos/scalpaca/blob/master/src/main/scala/model/account.scala))

**The Decoder**

Trying to compile the below code:

```
package model

import java.time.LocalDateTime

import cats.effect.IO
import cats.syntax.functor._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import org.http4s.EntityDecoder
import org.http4s.circe.jsonOf

package object account {

  sealed trait AccountStatus
  case object Onboarding       extends AccountStatus
  case object SubmissionFailed extends AccountStatus
  case object Submitted        extends AccountStatus
  case object AccountUpdated   extends AccountStatus
  case object ApprovalPending  extends AccountStatus
  case object Active           extends AccountStatus
  case object Rejected         extends AccountStatus

  object AccountStatus {

    implicit val accountStatusEncoder: Encoder[AccountStatus] = Encoder.instance {
      case onboarding@Onboarding => onboarding.asJson
      case submissionFailed@SubmissionFailed => submissionFailed.asJson
      case submitted@Submitted => submitted.asJson
      case accountUpdated@AccountUpdated => accountUpdated.asJson
      case approvalPending@ApprovalPending => approvalPending.asJson
      case active@Active => active.asJson
      case rejected@Rejected => rejected.asJson
    }

    implicit val accountStatusDecoder: Decoder[AccountStatus] =
      List[Decoder[AccountStatus]](
        Decoder[Onboarding].widen,
        Decoder[SubmissionFailed].widen,
        Decoder[Submitted].widen,
        Decoder[AccountUpdated].widen,
        Decoder[ApprovalPending].widen,
        Decoder[Active].widen,
        Decoder[Rejected].widen
      ).reduceLeft(_ or _)

    implicit val AccountStatusEntityDecoder = jsonOf[IO, AccountStatus]

  }


  case class Account(
                      id: String,
                      status: AccountStatus,
                      currency: String,
                      buyingPower: Double,
                      cash: Double,
                      cashWithdrawable: Double,
                      portfolioValue: Double,
                      patternDayTrader: Boolean,
                      tradingBlocked: Boolean,
                      transfersBlocked: Boolean,
                      accountBlocked: Boolean,
                      createdAt: LocalDateTime
                    )

  object Account {
    implicit val AccountDecoder: EntityDecoder[IO, Account] = jsonOf[IO, Account]
  }
```

}

results in the following errors:

```
[error] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:38:19: not found: type Onboarding
[error]           Decoder[Onboarding].widen,
[error]                   ^
[error] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:39:19: not found: type SubmissionFailed
[error]           Decoder[SubmissionFailed].widen,
[error]                   ^
[error] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:40:19: not found: type Submitted
[error]           Decoder[Submitted].widen,
[error]                   ^
[error] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:41:19: not found: type AccountUpdated
[error]           Decoder[AccountUpdated].widen,
[error]                   ^
[error] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:42:19: not found: type ApprovalPending
[error]           Decoder[ApprovalPending].widen,
[error]                   ^
[error] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:43:19: not found: type Active
[error]           Decoder[Active].widen,
[error]                   ^
[error] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:44:19: not found: type Rejected
[error]           Decoder[Rejected].widen
[error]                   ^
[error] 7 errors found
```

I find this rather confusing as the types the compiler complains about are quite clearly in scope, at least as far as I can tell.

**The Encoder**

Removing the decoder, the AccountStatusEntityDecoder that depends on it and the AccountStatus field from account, being left with the below

```
package model

import java.time.LocalDateTime

import cats.effect.IO
import cats.syntax.functor._
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import org.http4s.EntityDecoder
import org.http4s.circe.jsonOf

package object account {

  sealed trait AccountStatus
  case object Onboarding       extends AccountStatus
  case object SubmissionFailed extends AccountStatus
  case object Submitted        extends AccountStatus
  case object AccountUpdated   extends AccountStatus
  case object ApprovalPending  extends AccountStatus
  case object Active           extends AccountStatus
  case object Rejected         extends AccountStatus

  object AccountStatus {

    implicit val accountStatusEncoder: Encoder[AccountStatus] = Encoder.instance {
      case onboarding@Onboarding => onboarding.asJson
      case submissionFailed@SubmissionFailed => submissionFailed.asJson
      case submitted@Submitted => submitted.asJson
      case accountUpdated@AccountUpdated => accountUpdated.asJson
      case approvalPending@ApprovalPending => approvalPending.asJson
      case active@Active => active.asJson
      case rejected@Rejected => rejected.asJson
    }

  }

  case class Account(
                      id: String,
                      currency: String,
                      buyingPower: Double,
                      cash: Double,
                      cashWithdrawable: Double,
                      portfolioValue: Double,
                      patternDayTrader: Boolean,
                      tradingBlocked: Boolean,
                      transfersBlocked: Boolean,
                      accountBlocked: Boolean,
                      createdAt: LocalDateTime
                    )

  object Account {
    implicit val AccountDecoder: EntityDecoder[IO, Account] = jsonOf[IO, Account]
  }

}
```

I again get some warnings and errors:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/tom/code/scalpaca/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[warn] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:27:48: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Onboarding
[warn]       case onboarding@Onboarding => onboarding.asJson
[warn]                                                ^
[warn] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:28:66: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: SubmissionFailed
[warn]       case submissionFailed@SubmissionFailed => submissionFailed.asJson
[warn]                                                                  ^
[warn] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:29:45: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Submitted
[warn]       case submitted@Submitted => submitted.asJson
[warn]                                             ^
[warn] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:30:60: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: AccountUpdated
[warn]       case accountUpdated@AccountUpdated => accountUpdated.asJson
[warn]                                                            ^
[warn] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:31:63: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: ApprovalPending
[warn]       case approvalPending@ApprovalPending => approvalPending.asJson
[warn]                                                               ^
[warn] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:32:36: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Active
[warn]       case active@Active => active.asJson
[warn]                                    ^
[warn] /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala:33:42: match may not be exhaustive.
[warn] It would fail on the following input: Rejected
[warn]       case rejected@Rejected => rejected.asJson
[warn]                                          ^
[error] Error while emitting account.scala
[error] assertion failed: 
[error]   Cannot emit primitive conversion from Lmodel/account/package$AccountStatus; to Lmodel/account/package$Onboarding$; - account.scala
[error]      while compiling: /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala
[error]         during phase: jvm
[error]      library version: version 2.12.8
[error]     compiler version: version 2.12.8
[error]   reconstructed args: -bootclasspath /home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/home/tom/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/classes:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.8.jar -Ypartial-unification -classpath /home/tom/code/scalpaca/target/scala-2.12/classes:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-generic_2.12/jars/circe-generic_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-parser_2.12/jars/circe-parser_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-java8_2.12/jars/circe-java8_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/http4s-circe_2.12/jars/http4s-circe_2.12-0.20.0-M4.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/http4s-dsl_2.12/jars/http4s-dsl_2.12-0.20.0-M4.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/http4s-blaze-client_2.12/jars/http4s-blaze-client_2.12-0.20.0-M4.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.12/bundles/shapeless_2.12-2.3.3.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-jawn_2.12/jars/circe-jawn_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/http4s-jawn_2.12/jars/http4s-jawn_2.12-0.20.0-M4.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/http4s-client_2.12/jars/http4s-client_2.12-0.20.0-M4.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/http4s-blaze-core_2.12/jars/http4s-blaze-core_2.12-0.20.0-M4.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-core_2.12/jars/circe-core_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/macro-compat_2.12/jars/macro-compat_2.12-1.1.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/jawn-parser_2.12/jars/jawn-parser_2.12-0.14.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/jawn-fs2_2.12/jars/jawn-fs2_2.12-0.13.0.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/http4s-core_2.12/jars/http4s-core_2.12-0.20.0-M4.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/blaze-http_2.12/jars/blaze-http_2.12-0.14.0-M11.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/io.circe/circe-numbers_2.12/jars/circe-numbers_2.12-0.11.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.spire-math/jawn-parser_2.12/jars/jawn-parser_2.12-0.13.0.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/parboiled_2.12/jars/parboiled_2.12-1.0.0.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/co.fs2/fs2-io_2.12/jars/fs2-io_2.12-1.0.2.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.alpn/alpn-api/jars/alpn-api-1.1.3.v20160715.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/hpack/jars/hpack-1.0.2.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.http4s/blaze-core_2.12/jars/blaze-core_2.12-0.14.0-M11.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.log4s/log4s_2.12/jars/log4s_2.12-1.6.1.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/co.fs2/fs2-core_2.12/jars/fs2-core_2.12-1.0.2.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-effect_2.12/jars/cats-effect_2.12-1.1.0.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.scodec/scodec-bits_2.12/jars/scodec-bits_2.12-1.1.7.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-core_2.12/jars/cats-core_2.12-1.5.0.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-kernel_2.12/jars/cats-kernel_2.12-1.5.0.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/cats-macros_2.12/jars/cats-macros_2.12-1.5.0.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/machinist_2.12/jars/machinist_2.12-0.6.6.jar:/home/tom/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.6.jar
[error] 
[error]   last tree to typer: TypeTree(trait Decoder)
[error]        tree position: line 53 of /home/tom/code/scalpaca/src/main/scala/model/account.scala
[error]             tree tpe: io.circe.Decoder
[error]               symbol: abstract trait Decoder in package circe
[error]    symbol definition: abstract trait Decoder extends Serializable (a ClassSymbol)
[error]       symbol package: io.circe
[error]        symbol owners: trait Decoder
[error]            call site: constructor package$Account$anon$importedDecoder$macro$28$1$anon$macro$25$1 in package account
[error] 
[error] == Source file context for tree position ==
[error] 
[error]     50                     )
[error]     51 
[error]     52   object Account {
[error]     53     implicit val AccountDecoder: EntityDecoder[IO, Account] = jsonOf[IO, Account]
[error]     54   }
[error]     55 
[error]     56 }
[error] Error while emitting account.scala
[error] assertion failed: Cannot emit primitive conversion from Lmodel/account/package$AccountStatus; to Lmodel/account/package$SubmissionFailed$; - account.scala
[error] Error while emitting account.scala
[error] assertion failed: Cannot emit primitive conversion from Lmodel/account/package$AccountStatus; to Lmodel/account/package$Submitted$; - account.scala
[error] Error while emitting account.scala
[error] assertion failed: Cannot emit primitive conversion from Lmodel/account/package$AccountStatus; to Lmodel/account/package$AccountUpdated$; - account.scala
[error] Error while emitting account.scala
[error] assertion failed: Cannot emit primitive conversion from Lmodel/account/package$AccountStatus; to Lmodel/account/package$ApprovalPending$; - account.scala
[error] Error while emitting account.scala
[error] assertion failed: Cannot emit primitive conversion from Lmodel/account/package$AccountStatus; to Lmodel/account/package$Active$; - account.scala
[error] Error while emitting account.scala
[error] assertion failed: Cannot emit primitive conversion from Lmodel/account/package$AccountStatus; to Lmodel/account/package$Rejected$; - account.scala
[warn] 7 warnings found
[error] 7 errors found
```

I can't figure out why Account is affected. *If I remove the AccountStatus companion object entirely my project compiles.*

I'd like some help getting rid of these errors, your input would still be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have to add `.type` to the case objects in implicit val accountStatusDecoder: `Decoder[AccountStatus] = List[Decoder[AccountStatus]](
        Decoder[Onboarding.type].widen`, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Provide a complete answer to those who might stumble upon this question later:

stsatlantis' suggestion indeed solves one of the problems (thanks for your comment!), while the other one can be solved by slightly modifying the accountStatusEncoder. An alternative solution is to use case classes in your ADT, however, if you already have case objects it is probably because they better fit your needs/domain.

The changes I ended up going with:

```
  object AccountStatus {

  implicit val accountStatusEncoder: Encoder[AccountStatus] =
    Encoder.instance {
      status => status match {
          case Onboarding => status.asJson
          case SubmissionFailed => status.asJson
          case Submitted => status.asJson
          case AccountUpdated => status.asJson
          case ApprovalPending => status.asJson
          case Active => status.asJson
          case Rejected => status.asJson
      }
    }

  implicit val accountStatusDecoder: Decoder[AccountStatus] =
    List[Decoder[AccountStatus]](
      Decoder[Onboarding.type].widen,
      Decoder[SubmissionFailed.type].widen,
      Decoder[Submitted.type].widen,
      Decoder[AccountUpdated.type].widen,
      Decoder[ApprovalPending.type].widen,
      Decoder[Active.type].widen,
      Decoder[Rejected.type].widen
    ).reduceLeft(_ or _)

  implicit val AccountStatusEntityDecoder = jsonOf[IO, AccountStatus]
}
```

Comment: Thannks you very much for sharing the solution :)